# Python filter from Excel

Tags: python, excel, filter, automation, jupyter-notebook

I am working on to create a python automation program for Excel.

I wanted to divide the longitude based on the median number.

What I want to get data is :

```
1. get the median number of longitude from excel file,

2. separate longitude based on median number 
   ex) if median number > 91:
          allocate above 91 longitude to 'A'
       else:
          allocate below 91 longitude to 'B'
```

Below is my code:

```
for i in range(2, maxRow+1):        
  country = sheet.cell(i,7).value
  longitude = sheet.cell(i,6).value
  median = np.median(longitude)
  if country=="United States":
      print("Unnited States" + str(longitude))
```

Below is the output from this code.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHu9Q.png)

above the output is show all longitude in United States.
However, I want to filter only
1. filter median from all the longitude,
2. if median > longitude:
allocate longitudes to 'A'
else:
allocate longitudes to 'B'

Could anyone help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(2, maxRow+1):        
country = sheet.cell(i,7).value
longitude = sheet.cell(i,6).value
median = np.median(longitude)
if country=="United States" and int(longitude)>-91:
    print("Unnited States" + str(longitude))
```